# Select statement where one of the column values change dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I am trying to write a query as follows

```
select trading_day,trading_time,quantity,price from trade where trade_id=A903
```

Now for this trading_time the logic of extraction is
If the price above matches table trade_sb price and trade_id then that becomes trading time
if there is no match I go to another table trade_mb and search for match of price and trade_id 
If there is no match in both above cases the original query holds good.

I tried with rank but couldn't get the result

Please help

Comment: It would be nice if you posted test case. Reading what you wrote, *it looks like* (outer?) join with the NVL function.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, since it is in the form of a document with me i was not able to provide more details. Let me try what best i can give

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear to me but i think you can create a function for it and use it in the query, see sample code below,

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_trading_time (p_trade_id VARCHAR2, p_price NUMBER,  p_trading_time DATE) RETURN DATE
IS
       v_trading_time DATE;
BEGIN
       BEGIN
           SELECT trading_time
             INTO v_trading_time
             FROM trade_sb
            WHERE trade_id = p_trade_id
              AND price = p_price;
           RETURN v_trading_time;
       EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
       END;
       BEGIN
           SELECT trading_time
             INTO v_trading_time
             FROM trade_mb
            WHERE trade_id = p_trade_id
              AND prioe = p_price;
           RETURN v_trading_time;
       EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
       END;
       IF v_trading_time IS NULL THEN
          RETURN p_trading_time;
       END IF;
END;
/


select trading_day,trading_time,quantity,price ,
        get_trading_time(trade_id, price, trading_time) trading_time2
  from trade 
 where trade_id='A903';
```